# JWT Authentication Tokens With JSON:API

Tags: rest, json-api

I am creating a JSON API that implements the [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/format/) specification. I have a question about it however, and this question applies more generally to RESTful design in general: What is the recommended way to handle the "creation" of a resource, where one of the attributes is "calculated" by the server?

In my example, I have a `POST /auth/tokens` endpoint that accepts a user's credentials and returns a [JWT](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519). I've used a POST endpoint, because it seems to me that we are **creating** a token resource, even if that token is not saved to a database. However, according to JSON:API, what would the proper request/response look like? This?:

```json
POST /auth/tokens

{
  "data": {
    "type": "tokens",
    "attributes": {
      "email": "...",
      "password": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

However, does it even make sense to create a token **with** an email and password? It seems that it would be creating a token **for** an email/password. Is there a difference?

More importantly, what would the response look like? It seems like it would look something like:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "type": "tokens",
    "attributes": {
      "token": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

But the specification states:

> Every resource object MUST contain an id member and a type member. The values of the id and type members MUST be strings.

Since the tokens aren't saved to the database, I don't really have an ID for them. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

JSON:API specification doesn't say anything about such case but if you look on some live implementations like https://docs.unit.co/customer-api-tokens#customers-create-customer-bearer-token they use similar approach as you described. It seems to be just ok in this case to omit ID for a resource which is short lived.